# How to open a second activity on click of button in android app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am learning to build android applications and I need some specific help. I can't seem to get my head around which bits of template code I am required to change, and which bits are static.

In the **LAYOUT** folder I have my **ACTIVITY_MAIN.XML** which reads

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/main_buttons_photos" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Next, I have my second activity **ACTIVITY_SEND_PHOTOS.XML** which is

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".SendPhotos" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/title_activity_send_photos"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

I then have my **MainActivity.java** (is this the .class?) this reads
     package com.example.assent.bc;

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
     return true;
 }
 /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
 public void sendMessage(View view) {
     // Do something in response to button
 }
 }
```

and then my **SendPhotos.java** file which is;

```
 package com.example.assent.bc;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

 public class SendPhotos extends Activity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_photos);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_send_photos, menu);
    return true;
 }


 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

 }
```

I would like the button in my main activity to link through to my sendphotos activity, simply opening up that activity, nothing fancy, not sending any data or anything.

I know that somewhere I need my

```
 Intent i = new Intent(FromActivity.this, ToActivity.class);
 startActivity(i);
```

but I have no idea what to replace **ToActivity.class** with or what else I need where.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Intent in an Android application to show another activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736571/using-intent-in-an-android-application-to-show-another-activity)

Comment: ToActivity.class is your secondactivity name

Comment: [This](http://themasterworld.com/in-this-lecture-we-will-see-how-to-start-a-new-activity-on-a-button-click-in-the-current-activity/) can be the best source for you

Comment: Intent class do not have any constructor that accept two class as argment!. what should I do?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You can move to desired activity on button click. just add this line.

`android:onClick="sendMessage"`

**xml:**

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/button" />
```

In your main activity just add this method:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(FromActivity.this, ToActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And the most important thing: don't forget to define your activity in `manifest.xml`

```
 <activity
      android:name=".ToActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

Comment: You must add `>` in the activity tag

Comment: This is not working for me. The `View` , `Intent` and the activity names are in red. Do I need to import anything for View?

Comment: @SrujanBarai yes, both import android.view.View; and import android.content.Intent; must be imported

Comment: It worked fine for me. However doesn't he need a setOnClickListener() on his button?

Comment: @VaggelisManousakis no its not required because it is already there in xml `android:onClick="sendMessage"`

Answer (score 30):

Try this

```
  Button button;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SendPhotos.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

 }
```

Comment: but where? I get errors all over the place If i try place this withing the .java in eclipse

Comment: @HenryAspden import onclocklistener and Button.

Comment: @HenryAspden put this code after onCreate and after finding your id.

Comment: @HenryAspden i have edit my code now try this. i have put this code in onCreate try this way.

Answer (score 13):

From Activity : where you are currently ?

To Activity :  where you want to go ?

`Intent i = new Intent( MainActivity.this, SendPhotos.class); 
startActivity(i);`

Both Activity must be included in manifest file otherwise it will not found the class file and throw Force close.

Edit your Mainactivity.java

```
crate button's object;
```

now Write code for click event.

```
        Button btn = (button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
         btn.LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
       {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                 //put your intent code here
                }
   });
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: does this go within the layout or the .java?

Comment: ok you can put this code in button's click event in main activity.java file

Answer (score 12):

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);       
    }  
});
```

The answer for the complete noob from a complete noob:
`MainActivity` is the name of the first activity.
`MainActivity2` is the name of the second activity.
`button1` is the I.D of the button in xml for `MainActivity` Activity.

Comment: just to help others... by "name of the button" are you refering to the ID?

Comment: Indeed .  Corrected to reflect your reccomendation

Answer (score 5):

just follow this step (i am not writing code just Bcoz you may do copy and paste and cant learn)..

1. first at all you need to declare a button which you have in layout
2. Give reference to that button by finding its id (using findviewById) in oncreate
3. setlistener for button (like setonclick listener)
4. last handle the click event (means start new activity by using intent as you know already)
5. Dont forget to add activity in manifest file

BTW this is just simple i would like to suggest you that just start from simple tutorials available
on net will be better for you..

Best luck for Android

Answer (score 4):

Replace the below line code:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
   Button button;
    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
      }
       public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId==R.id.button1){
      Intent i = new Intent(FromActivity.this, ToActivity.class);
               startActivity(i);
            }
        }
     }
```

Add the below lines in your manifest file:

```
   <activity android:name="com.packagename.FromActivity"></activity>
   <activity android:name="com.packagename.ToActivity"></activity>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Replace your MainActivity.class with these code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener()
 {
  public void onClick(View v)
   {
       Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SendPhotos.class);
       startActivity(i);
    }
 }
 )
}
```

**Add these Code in your** `AndroidManifest.xml` after the `</activity>` and Before `</application>`

```
<activity android:name=".SendPhotos"></activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

This always works, either one should be just fine:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.tobidae.Activity1"));
        }
        //** OR you can just use the one down here instead, both work either way
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChemistryActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add below code to activity_main.xml file:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="buttonClick"
        android:text="@string/button" />
```

and just add the below method to the MainActivity.java file:

```
public void buttonClick(View view){
  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext()SendPhotos.class);
  startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in, a question mark before the name of the file

Comment: Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

If you have two buttons and have the same id call to your button click events like this:

```
Button btn1;
Button btn2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,target.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btn2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);//Have same id call previous button---> button1

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

When you clicked `button1`, `button2` will work and you cannot open your second activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circal"
            android:text="Sign in"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etPasswordLogin" />
```

IN JAVA CODE

```
Button signIn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);

signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SignInPage.this,MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can move to desired activity on button click. just add
android:onClick="timerApp"this line.

```
xml:

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/timer_app"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="timerApp"
        android:text="Click To run Timer Activity" />
```

In your main activity just add this method:

```
 public void timerApp(View view){
        Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,TimerActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

OR in onCreate() method add below code

```
Button btn =findViewById(R.id.timer_app);//Don't need to type casting in android studio 3

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimerActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);       
    }  
});
```