# SQLite Delete Objects on Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm new to android and I'm working on a scheduling app.  I've been using SQLite to store data onto my device and it's been working, however, I do have a delete button that I'm trying to also use to get rid of the item found in the list view.

This is my DatabaseHandler.java code:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "assignmentManager",
    TABLE_ASSIGNMENTS = "assignments",
    KEY_ID = "id",
    KEY_NAME = "name",
    KEY_TIME = "time",
    KEY_ASSIGNED = "assigned",
    KEY_DUE = "due";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context)
{
    super( context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION );
}

@Override
public void onCreate( SQLiteDatabase db )
{
    db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ASSIGNMENTS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_TIME + " INTEGER," + KEY_ASSIGNED + " TEXT," + KEY_DUE + " TEXT )" );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade( SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion )
{
    db.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ASSIGNMENTS );

    onCreate( db );
}

public void createAssignment( Assignment assignment )
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put( KEY_NAME, assignment.getName() );
    values.put( KEY_TIME, assignment.getTime() );
    values.put( KEY_ASSIGNED, assignment.getAssigned() );
    values.put( KEY_DUE, assignment.getDue() );

    db.insert( TABLE_ASSIGNMENTS, null, values );
    db.close();
}

public Assignment getAssignment( int id )
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query( TABLE_ASSIGNMENTS, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_TIME, KEY_ASSIGNED, KEY_DUE }, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null );

    if ( cursor != null )
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    GregorianCalendar dateDue = new GregorianCalendar( Assignment.getYear( cursor.getString( 4 ) ), Assignment.getMonth(cursor.getString(4)), Assignment.getDay(cursor.getString(4)) );
    GregorianCalendar dateAssigned = new GregorianCalendar( Assignment.getYear( cursor.getString( 3 ) ), Assignment.getMonth( cursor.getString( 3 ) ), Assignment.getDay( cursor.getString( 3 ) ) );

    Assignment assignment = new Assignment( Integer.parseInt( cursor.getString( 0 ) ), cursor.getString( 1 ), dateDue, dateAssigned, Integer.parseInt( cursor.getString( 2 ) ) );
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return assignment;
}

public void deleteAssignment( Assignment assignment )
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete( TABLE_ASSIGNMENTS, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf( assignment.getId() ) } );
    db.close();
}

public int getAssignmentsCount()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ASSIGNMENTS, null );
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();

    return count;
}

public int updateAssignment( Assignment assignment )
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put( KEY_NAME, assignment.getName() );
    values.put( KEY_TIME, assignment.getTime() );
    values.put( KEY_ASSIGNED, assignment.getAssigned() );
    values.put( KEY_DUE, assignment.getDue() );

    return db.update( TABLE_ASSIGNMENTS, values, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf( assignment.getId() ) } );
}

public List<Assignment> getAllAssignments()
{
    List<Assignment> assignments = new ArrayList<Assignment>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ASSIGNMENTS, null );

    if ( cursor.moveToFirst() )
    {
        do {
            {
                GregorianCalendar dateDue = new GregorianCalendar( Assignment.getYear( cursor.getString( 4 ) ), Assignment.getMonth(cursor.getString(4)), Assignment.getDay(cursor.getString(4)) );
                GregorianCalendar dateAssigned = new GregorianCalendar( Assignment.getYear( cursor.getString( 3 ) ), Assignment.getMonth( cursor.getString( 3 ) ), Assignment.getDay( cursor.getString( 3 ) ) );

                Assignment assignment = new Assignment( Integer.parseInt( cursor.getString( 0 ) ), cursor.getString( 1 ), dateDue, dateAssigned, Integer.parseInt( cursor.getString( 2 ) ) );
                assignments.add( assignment );
            }
        }
        while ( cursor.moveToNext() );
    }
    return assignments;
}
```

This is my TeacherActivity.java code:

```
List<Assignment> a = new ArrayList<Assignment>();
ListView aListView;
DatabaseHandler dbHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_teachers);

    TextView teachers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.teachers);
    TextView create = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.create);
    TextView assignments = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.assignments);
    final EditText assignmentname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.assignmentname);
    final DatePicker due = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.due);
    final EditText time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time);
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    final Button createassignment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createassignment);
    aListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler( getApplicationContext() );

    tabHost.setup();
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("add");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabAdder);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Add");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("assignments");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabAssignments);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Assignments");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    Typeface arvo = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/arvo.otf");
    Typeface bebas = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/bebas.otf");

    teachers.setTypeface(arvo);
    create.setTypeface(bebas);
    assignmentname.setTypeface(bebas);
    time.setTypeface(bebas);
    createassignment.setTypeface(bebas);
    assignments.setTypeface(bebas);

    createassignment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GregorianCalendar gd = new GregorianCalendar( due.getYear(), due.getMonth(), due.getDayOfMonth() );
            Assignment assignment = new Assignment( dbHandler.getAssignmentsCount(), String.valueOf( assignmentname.getText() ), gd, new GregorianCalendar(), Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(time.getText())) );
            dbHandler.createAssignment( assignment );
            a.add( assignment );
            populateList();

            assignmentname.setText("");
            time.setText("");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Assignment created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    assignmentname.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            createassignment.setEnabled(!assignmentname.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    teachers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(TeachersActivity.this, MainActivity.class);  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/13194141/2869358
            startActivity(i);  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/13194141/2869358
        }
    });

    List<Assignment> addableAssignments = dbHandler.getAllAssignments();
    int assignmentCount = dbHandler.getAssignmentsCount();

    for ( int i = 0; i < assignmentCount; i++ )
    {
        a.add( addableAssignments.get( i ) );
    }

    if ( !addableAssignments.isEmpty() )
    {
        populateList();
    }
}

private void populateList()
{
    ArrayAdapter<Assignment> adapter = new AssignmentListAdapter();
    aListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void addAssignments( String name, GregorianCalendar dateDue, int time )
{
    a.add( new Assignment( 0, name, dateDue, new GregorianCalendar(), time ));
    Collections.sort(a);
}

private class AssignmentListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Assignment>
{

    Typeface arvo = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/arvo.otf");
    Typeface bebas = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/bebas.otf");

    public AssignmentListAdapter()
    {
        super ( TeachersActivity.this, R.layout.listview_assignments, a );
    }

    @Override
    public View getView( final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent )
    {
        if ( view == null )
        {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.listview_assignments, parent, false );
        }

        Assignment currentAssignment = a.get( position );

        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler( getApplicationContext() );
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView due = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.due);
        TextView time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
        TextView assigned = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.assigned);
        Button delete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.delete);

        name.setTypeface(bebas);
        due.setTypeface(bebas);
        time.setTypeface(bebas);
        assigned.setTypeface(bebas);
        delete.setTypeface(arvo);

        name.setText(currentAssignment.getName());
        due.setText("Due: " + currentAssignment.getDue());
        time.setText("Estimated Time: " + currentAssignment.getTimeString());
        assigned.setText("Assigned: " + currentAssignment.getAssigned());

        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dbHandler.deleteAssignment( a.get( position ) );
                remove(a.get(position));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.teachers, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The delete button can be found in the **getView()** method of the TeacherActivity.java class.

I don't know if I'm using the **deleteAssignment()** method correctly.

Please help!

Comment: Seems correct. What is the problem?

Comment: I would recommend do all DB operations in an AsynTask