# Android: Redirect to another Activity after delay

Tags: java, android, facebook, redirect

So I am developing a simple app for a college project, And I have been able to integrate a Facebook login using fragments.

But I now am stuck trying to redirect the user after they login. I simply want to redirect them to the second activity page

Here is my code for the Facebook login success

```
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback=new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        if (profile != null) {
            display.setText("Welcome: " + profile.getFirstName());
            //Redirect to Second Activity

        }

}
```

Comment: So are you having problems adding the delay, or doing the redirect, or both?

Comment: Similar question asked here: [start second activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194081/how-to-open-a-second-activity-on-click-of-button-in-android-app)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start new activity on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

Comment: @DavidMedenjak How is it a duplicate the question u posted is about attaching to a button click ? mine asks about redirecting after a time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make a delayed transition use `Handler` class's `postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)` method, for example:

**Java**

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // if you are redirecting from a fragment 
        // then use getActivity() as the context.
        startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, TargetActivity.class));
    }
};
    
Handler h = new Handler();
// The Runnable will be executed after the given delay time
h.postDelayed(r, 1500); // will be delayed for 1.5 seconds
```

**Kotlin** with **Anko**

```
val someThread = Runnable {
    startActivity(intentFor<TargetActivity>())
}

Handler().postDelayed(someThread, 1500)
```

Comment: Yeah see the problem is the same as what I had before my intent doesnt work "                Intent i3 = new Intent(FLogin.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i3);" Flogin is not an enclosed class/ and if I change it to the fragement name it just breaks the whole line saying cannot resolve

Comment: Is the Flogin an Activity?

Comment: The intent needs the current context as argument, if you are in a fragment use `getActivity()`

Comment: You should use `getActivity()` for current context if you're inside a fragment.

Comment: Pleasure's all mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply call a new activity through intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: Yeah see the problem is the same as what I had before my intent doesnt work "                Intent i3 = new Intent(FLogin.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i3);" Flogin is not an enclosed class/ and if I change it to the fragement name it just breaks the whole line saying cannot resolve

Comment: If calling through a fragment then you should use this.getActivity() instead.
So,
Intent i = new Intent(this.getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();

Answer (score 1):

Check this:-

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {

                      Intent i=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,Next.class);
                      startActivity(i);
                  }
              }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

> A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects
>   associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is
>   associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When
>   you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of
>   the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver
>   messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they
>   come out of the message queue.

You can use **Handler** `postDelayed` Method easily .

```
Handler hd = new Handler();
            hd.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

               // Add Your Intent

             }

            }, 2000); // Time Delay ,2 Seconds 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin;

```
  val r = Runnable {

        startActivity(Intent(this, AuthorActivity::class.java))
    }
    val h = Handler()

    h.postDelayed(r, 10)
```