# Link 2 buttons with 2 different Activitys

Tags: android

I have created an homepage with 2 buttons and i want to link the first button with the main activity and the second button with the main 2 activity. What Ihave to do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here you have the oficial "tutorial" on how to do it --> . https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html?hl=es

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a second activity on click of button in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194081/how-to-open-a-second-activity-on-click-of-button-in-android-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this through xml too

```
  <Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/fields_margin_bottom"
android:text="Activity1"
android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
android:textAllCaps="true"
android:textSize="@dimen/size"
android:onClick="mainActivty"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/fields_margin_bottom"
android:text="Activity2"
android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
android:textAllCaps="true"
android:textSize="@dimen/size"
android:onClick="main2Activty"/>
```

And then implement those methods in your Homepage activity

```
public void mainActivty(View v) {

  startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
}

public void main2Activty(View v) {

  startActivity(new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            }
        });

b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

[How to start new activity on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click)

For instance, in onCreate() write:

```
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity1.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);}
        });

    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity2.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);}
        });
```