# How to handle click from xml to Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, daemon

I am new to android and following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK0QNA0sMGc&t=2710s
(*It's in Hindi*)

In my **MainActivity.java**:

[image: In my MainActivity.java]

When I'm trying to run the app it's giving errors saying:

```
9 errors found
1 warning found
2 typos found
```

It's asking me to put a semicolon at the end of
`Log.i(tag:"this", msg:"clickbtn: This is a message");`

which I have already put down.

This is my **activity_main.xml**:
[image: acitivity_main.xml file]

Can anybody tell me what are the errors?

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/topText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:text="Welcome to Shivam Travels"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter your username"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/topText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter your password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:onClick="clickbtn"
    android:text="Sign In"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="176dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Remember me!"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />
```

Comment: also show your xml code

Comment: It is above in the form of an image.

Comment: can you show me the code xml code?

Comment: I added it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You took the code from a screenshot. The problem is that Android studio added information that shows the name of the parameter when you call a method using literals.

This information is not part of the code and Android Studio just adds it to inform you about the parameter and make the code more readable.

The actual code should be:

```
Log.i("this", "clickbtn: this is a message");
```

instead of:

```
Log.i(tag:"this", msg:"clickbtn: this is a message");
```

If you use this, Android Studio will show you the `tag:` and `message:` even if it is not part of your code.

Answer (score 3):

Replace you code with this code

Replace

```
Log.i(tag:"this", msg:"clickbtn: This is a message");
```

with

```
Log.i("This","This is a message");
```

Below full snippet of you code

**JAVA FILE**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainTestActivity extends Activity {
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void clickbtn(View view){
        Log.i("This","This is a message");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:text="Welcome to Shivam Travels"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/topText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topText" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:onClick="clickbtn"
        android:text="Sign In"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="176dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Remember me!"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]
For more details : [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194081/how-to-open-a-second-activity-on-click-of-button-in-android-app)

Hope this may helps you now.

Comment: Do I have to add your XML code in addition to my XML code or replace my code with yours?

Comment: Right now i'm just give example...wait i'll create modification into your code. but you can get a click in a right way like this. insteadof use android:onClick="clickbtn" in XML

Comment: Thanks a lot but since I have just started learning I can't figure out most of the java file but it worked without errors. :) Thanks again!

Comment: It's working now or not? check updated answer again and  look below cliked text appeared.

Answer (score 2):

Remove **tag:** and **msg:** from your code

Comment: its is not a text it's a suggestion brother this is not a error @ajay

Comment: @InsaneCat I know that but here, he is a new bie and not aware of suggestions and how to handle it

Comment: But you mentioned this is error but this is not written his code.

Comment: i had removed that mention

Comment: I understand the suggestion now after going through the code. I had to put strings and the tag and msg would be suggestions but I hardcoded them. I got it now!

Comment: Good enjoy coding :) @AjayKS

Answer (score 2):

You define above type not supported in java.You can do like this.

```
public String tag = "this";
public String msg = "clickbtn:this is a message!";


Log.i(tag,msg);
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
Log.i(tag:"this", msg:"clickbtn: This is a message");
```

with

```
Log.i("this","clickbtn:this is a message!");
```