# error while moving to next page in android studio

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private Button b;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.q);
            b.setOnClickListener(movetonext(););
        }
        public void movetonext()
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,go.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dear VISH Welcome to SO. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194081/how-to-open-a-second-activity-on-click-of-button-in-android-app

Comment: b.setOnClickListener(movetonext(););
This is not even how Android works. Please see how onClickListener is implemented in Android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a second activity on click of button in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194081/how-to-open-a-second-activity-on-click-of-button-in-android-app)

Answer (score 1):

Change your click listener like below -

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                movetonext();
            }
        });
```

Hope this will help you.