# How to change the activity using a method and call it

Tags: android

```
public void changeActivity(Context context){
        Intent intent =new Intent(this,context.getClass());
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.register:
               changeActivity(RegisterActivity);
               break;
    }
}
```

I am using a 'changeActivity' method but I got error in line 10. The error pointed that 'Expression Expected'

Comment: change `context.getClass` this to method call `context.getClass()` like this.

Comment: sorry , it is my mistake of brackets but i got the error in line 10 of 'changeActivity(RegisterActivity);'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How do you go to another activity on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163481/android-how-do-you-go-to-another-activity-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

You have pass an class object of your desination activity in your changeActivity method like this:

```
public void changeActivity(Class<? extends Activity> desinationActivity) { 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, destinationActivity);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.register:
               changeActivity(RegisterActivity.class); 
               break;
    }
}
```

You can check out this [link](https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/mobile-apps/how-to-use-a-context-to-start-a-specific-activity-in-your-android-app/) for reference. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing your class file as object to `Intent` when you start activity.

Find out below solution :

```
public void changeActivity(Class<? extends Activity> context) { // Receive it here and provide to your intent.
    Intent intent =new Intent(this, context);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.register:
               changeActivity(RegisterActivity.class); // pass object of your desired activity as class parameter here
               break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For writing this type of code you can check system source code. Following code of Intent constructor:

```
public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
    mComponent = new ComponentName(packageContext, cls);
}
```